# Formula helps to extract value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-365

0

Please need a formula to get the NUMBER after the "SV in the description. In the 1st row, want to extract the 1 and in the 3rd, row want the @1 AND Fourth row want the 10.

CONSTENT.1 SN.1 AMMI FLEX 2401865776

CONSTENT.1 SN.1 METER READS 3386. AMMI FLEX 24007779.

RF SN & PULSE SN-@1 RIO, CON-1 ZDG015-685103 RDGFRTG-0653

RF SN & PULSER, SN-10, HANGER DEVICE,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example : 
RF SN & PULSE SN-@1 RIO, CON-1 ZDG015-685103 RDGFRTG-0653-------want to get @1

RF SN & PULSER, SN-10, HANGER DEVICE-----want to get 10

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the following formulas are helpful.

`=IFERROR(FIND("SN.",A1),FIND("SN-",A1))` this formula can help us find the number of positions for "SN." and "SN-".

[image]

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-G1-2)` this formula can extract the strings that start with values that you want.

[image]

`=IF(IFERROR(FIND(",",H1),200)>FIND(" ",H1),FIND(" ",H1),FIND(",",H1))` can get position of the first occurrence of a space or comma.

[image]

The last formula `=LEFT(H1,I1-1)` can get the values that you want.

[image]